# css div height 100% problem?

Tags: css, html, height

I would like a div to take all the screen height, that's why I found the following links:

- http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/200.htm
- http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/100-percent-height-interface

the tricks: make the container have a specified height, for example: `body{height:100%}` seems work fine, however, I found that: once you add some doctype claim, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

It doesn't work, at least at Firefox 3.*, it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me in HTML 4.01 strict (from your second link).  No vertical scroll bar is displayed, even if the `body` is very long.  Does this work for you?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body {
      /* get rid of default spacing on the edges */
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;

      /* get rid of that 2px window border in Internet Explorer 6 */
      border: 0;

      /* fill the height of the browser */
      height: 100%;

      /* no more scroll bar */
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      many many lines of text
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I noticed that the doctype is not important, the key is: not only add height:100% to body, but also to html