# How to resize background image?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I followed a tutorial about resizing background images on this link

[How To: Resizeable Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/)

I was trying to edit it to work on div with width of 900px so it will resize only vertically and I have no idea how to make it work.

Any one can tell me how to do it as I want.

Thanks

Comment: So, your background-image should always be 900px wide and change only it's vertical size?

Comment: What about using the background image as a normal image beneath the actual div and resizing that image?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the first, second or third approach?

Considering the third approach, it might simply work if you change *width* to *height*:

```
#img.source-image {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

In case this doesn't work, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892052/css-div-height-100-problem) and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982180/css-100-percent-height-body-and-element) and experiment with your body height and `DOCTYPE`. You might also want to ask the same question on [doctype.com](http://doctype.com).

Comment: Plus he should add "width: 900px;"

Comment: As a note, doctype.com closed as of February 15, 2013. [Read more about it](http://blog.doctype.com/doctype_is_closing_on_the_14th_1).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this:

```
#yourDiv{
    background-size:cover}
```

But the compatibility [is limited.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/UVj2j/).

Comment: This is the CSS3 property that controls background size. I haven't tried it, but would expect it to work in Webkit based browsers too.